# Clojure: I am using http-kit to post a request to a server, but it is not working well for me

Tags: clojure, http-kit

NOTE: I resolved my issue. However, it took a number of incremental changes. If you happen upon this page, feel free to checkout my github below to see how I made this application work.

---

I am using http-kit to post a request to btc-china. I want to use their trading api. I am able to do this just fine with python, but for some reason I keep getting 401s with clojure and http-kit. I've posted a snippit of code below which may show that I am not using http-kit correctly. In addition to that, here is a github for my full code if you wish to look at that: https://github.com/gilmaso/btc-trading
Here are the btc-china api docs: http://btcchina.org/api-trade-documentation-en

```
(def options {:timeout 2000 ; ms
          :query-params (sorted-map :tonce tonce
                                    :accesskey access-key
                                    :requestmethod request-method
                                    :id tonce
                                    :method method
                                    :params "")
          :headers {"Authorization" auth-string
                    "Json-Rpc-Tonce" tonce}})

(client/post (str "https://" base-url) options
      (fn [{:keys [status headers body error]}] ;; asynchronous handle response
        (if error
          (println "Failed, exception is " error)
          (println "Async HTTP GET: " status))))
```

Comment: Have you tried comparing the actual HTTP exchanges in either case? Maybe seeing the difference would give you a hint.

Comment: 9000, I am actually not sure how to do that in clojure or python :/

Comment: a program like [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) will let you record http traffic, and analyze it at your convenience

Answer (score 4, accepted):

quoting from the [example on the bttchina site](http://btcchina.org/api-trade-documentation-en):

```
# The order of params is critical for calculating a correct hash
```

clojure hash maps are unordered, and you cannot use a clojure hash map literal to provide the input if order is significant

Comment: I figured that the order would only matter for the hash itself but not for the query parameters. That being said, it looks like both clj-http and http-kit only allow for hashmaps for their query parameters.

Comment: @user3081629 you can use sorted-map/sorted-map-by (or just sort map) for hash calculation

Comment: edbond, I went back and changed the map to a sorted-map. I should have thought of that myself, but I'm really new to clojure. That being said, the 401s still persist.

Answer (score 1):

I had very similar problem with bitstamp api. The solution was to replace `:query-params` with `:form-params`. Then the parameters are sent in the body. I noticed that in your api you are manually sending then in the body. It looks like using `:form-params` might help in your case as well.